# Delete list of files in python

Tags: python, shutil

I am trying to clean USB drive and I have specified most of the unnecessary folders and files. the following code is very good

```
import os
import shutil
import hashlib

def delete_files_and_folders_on_usb_drive(usb_drive_path, filenames_to_delete, folder_prefixes, target_hash):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(usb_drive_path, topdown=False):
        for name in files + dirs:
            if (name in filenames_to_delete) or any(name.startswith(prefix) for prefix in folder_prefixes) or (name == '534') or (name.endswith('.exe')):
                path = os.path.join(root, name)
                try:
                    if os.path.isdir(path):
                        if name.endswith('.exe') and os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(path)) == os.path.splitext(name)[0]:
                            with open(path, 'rb') as f:
                                file_hash = hashlib.sha256(f.read()).hexdigest()
                            if file_hash == target_hash:
                                os.remove(path)
                        else:
                            if name.startswith('very important'):
                                for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
                                    for dirname in dirnames:
                                        os.chmod(os.path.join(dirpath, dirname), 0o777)
                                    for filename in filenames:
                                        os.chmod(os.path.join(dirpath, filename), 0o777)
                            if os.path.exists(path) and name in filenames_to_delete:
                                os.remove(path)
                            else:
                                shutil.rmtree(path, ignore_errors=True)
                    else:
                        with open(path, 'rb') as f:
                            file_hash = hashlib.sha256(f.read()).hexdigest()
                        if file_hash == target_hash:
                            print(path)
                            os.remove(path)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f'Failure {path}: {e}')

filenames_to_delete = ['Files.bat', 'MyText.txt']
folder_prefixes = ['new folder', 'very important', 'hackfolder']
target_hash = '9b57e6a137882be5a6e8c085cfa23f26294c2ac9427a99d0e54e9d26fc46c087'
delete_files_and_folders_on_usb_drive('I:/', filenames_to_delete, folder_prefixes, target_hash)
```

The only problem with the code is that it doesn't deal with the list of the files in this list `filenames_to_delete = ['Files.bat', 'MyText.txt']` but the folders are deleted successfully.

Comment: You could have done this with a batch file or a shell script in far less time than it took you to write this code, and you'd already be done.

Comment: Please provide a *minimal* reproducible example. Have you seen how many lines of code have nothing to do with `filenames_to_delete`?!

Answer (score 2):

Look at this section:

```
if os.path.isdir(path):
    if name.endswith('.exe') and os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(path)) == os.path.splitext(name)[0]:
        ...
        if file_hash == target_hash:
            os.remove(path)
    else:
        ...
        if os.path.exists(path) and name in filenames_to_delete:
            os.remove(path)
```

It's all inside the `if os.path.isdir(path)` block, so it doesn't run at all for files.